# galen: how to wait dynamic new page with same url

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, galen

I started working with Galen and I had this test that was working perfectly:

```
this.HomePage = $page('Welcome Page', {
    aboutButton: 'nav.navbar .about'
});

this.AboutPage = $page('About page', {
    modalContent: 'div.modal-content',
    supportLink: '.support-link',
    dismissButton: '.dismiss'
});


var homePage = new HomePage(driver);
homePage.waitForIt();
homePage.aboutButton.click();

var aboutPage = new AboutPage(driver);
aboutPage.waitForIt();
```

I understand that the `waitForIt` method waits for all the attributes defined by page so the framework knows when to execute the next statement.

Now, I want to run this as a grunt task and I've been using [`grunt-galenframework`](https://github.com/hypery2k/grunt-galenframework), and I configured it correctly, everything is working, but I can't make the previous test pass, the task code is as follows:

```
load('../gl.js');

forAll(config.getDevices(), function (device) {
    test('simple test on ' + device.deviceName, function () {
        gl.openPage(device, config.getProjectPage(), "Welcome Page", {
            aboutButton: 'nav.navbar .about'
        });

        elements.aboutButton.click();

        // MISSING WAIT FOR ABOUT_PAGE

        gl.runSpecFile(device, './test/responsive/galen/about.gspec');
    });
});
```

As you can see, I get into the `Welcome Page` and then I need to click a button, **wait for a dialog to appear**, and then check the `about.gspec` specs (they verify elements inside the dialog).

**So how can I add a wait for new elements to appear on the same URL?** it feels like `grunt-galenframework` only offers `wait` when entering a new url, with the `openPage` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try

```
elements.newElement.waitToBeShown()
```

The methods from [here](http://galenframework.com/docs/reference-galenpages-javascript-api/#GalenPagesPageElement) should be available.

PS: I'm the author of the grunt plugin for Galen and also involved in the development of the Galen Framework itself